# Sphinx Search Engine + .Net : How Can I Connect to Sphinx through C#?

Tags: c#, connection, sphinx

I installed and configured sphinx search engine (v. 2.2.11) in ubuntu and integrated it with oracle database to retrieve and index data from oracle. I also can submit query through sql client of sphinx by using command line and every thing is ok.

Now my question is: How can I connect to sphinx through C#? There is no official API for .Net.َAlthough there are several 3rd party APIs, some of them not free and some will not be updated anymore. I also saw SphinxSE that is a mysql storage engine and According to what I understood, Only used when data is stored in mysql but my data is stored in oracle and I use odbc for integrating oracle and sphinx.

So, Should I write an api myself or there may be other ways?

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use SphinxQL and connect to your Sphinx instance using any mysql library. Just make sure sphinxql is enabled in your config, you should have smth like this:

```
listen                       = 9314:mysql41
```

This tells Sphinx to accept connections from mysql clients on port 9314.

Comment: yes, I searched a lot of time and finally I can connect to Sphinx using the tutorial given on this link: http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/04/03/sphinxql-and-the-mysql-net-connector/       . Some new parameters (like mysql_version_string ) must be set and also the port number is 9306. Is there any reason to use 9314 port number?

Comment: No special reason to use 9314.